# stream: how to get row as array (instead of JSON object)

Tags: pg-promise

We need to export data to a csv file.

I think a nice approach is to use the streaming feature of pg-promise 
[Learn-by-Example#from-database](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#from-database)

It seems that the [stream](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#stream) reads the data from the db and transforms the row-data to a JSON object. Then we need to convert the JSON object back to an array and do the csv export.

Is there a way to configure the streaming feature to directly return the rows as array to improve performance (and avoid the useless JSON conversion)?
i.e. something like [ParameterizedQuery](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/ParameterizedQuery.html).rowMode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Library `pg-promise` in this cases solely relies on the [underlying driver](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) for data streaming, which unfortunately does not support such feature. It only lets you get JSON objects from the stream.

Comment: I've filed a [feature request](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-query-stream/issues/55) for pg-query-stream